# How to convert IP Address to GeoLocation using ASP.Net or Razor Systax or Bing Map?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, bing, webmatrix

I build the ASP.Net (.cshtml) site, and I need to get current location of user to show in Bing Map. How can I do this feature?

Answer (score 2):

MaxMind offers a IP geolocation library and API, see:  http://www.maxmind.com/app/api

They offer a number of Windows APIs, including C#.  see:  http://www.maxmind.com/app/windows

(Disclaimer:  not affiliated, just a happy customer.  I've not used the Windows APIs).

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't ever try to implement this myself. Using HTML5 you can actually get the best location available for the computer/device trying to view the page. One of the fallbacks that browsers use when there isn't a GPS device attached it to lookup the location of the IP address. This only works in HTML5 browsers but it's a very fast and cheap solution.

Javascript:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(show_map);

function show_map(position) {
   var lat = position.coords.latitude;
   var lng = position.coords.longitude;
}
```

If you want more details I find this site really useful.

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/geolocation.html

Answer (score 1):

did you checked nerddinner tutorial, chapter 11: Integration with an ajax map? http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part11.htm

Nerddinner uses js files -included in the example - plus a location request - included in the example too - .

to download files http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets if you want razor´s examples, otherwise http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/
Full tutorial starts here http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm
brgds.